# Codeigniter get random record with limit

Tags: sql, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

I've created a page that load 4 products everytime you scroll down the page with codeigniter and Ajax.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.thetutorialblog.com/php/twitter-like-pagination-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/) for create pagination with codeigniter and jQuery.
Everything works fine, moreover I've changed the load type from database using Ajax.

I've got a problem with codeigniter.
When I try to get random record from the table I've got duplicate products.

This is the functions in codeigniter:

UPDATE CONTROLLER

```
function index()
{
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $data['description'] = "Description";
  $data['keywords'] = "Keywords";
  $data['products'] = $this->abitainterni->getAllProductsLimit();
  $data['get_products'] = $this->abitainterni->get_products();
  $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
}

function get_products($offset)
{
    $already_used = $this->input->post('already_used');
    $already = explode(',', $already_used);
    $data['products'] = $this->abitainterni->getAllProductsLimit($offset, $already);
    $arr['view'] = $this->load->view('get_products', $data, true);
    $bossy = '';

    foreach($data['products'] as $p) {
      $bossy .= $p->productID.',';
    }
    $arr['view'] = $bam;
    $arr['ids'] = $bossy;
    echo json_encode($arr);

    return;
}
```

UPDATE SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

<?
    $like_a_boss = "";

    foreach($products as $gp):
        $like_a_boss .= $gp->productID.',';
    endforeach;
?>

    var products = '<?= $like_a_boss; ?>';
    var loaded_products = 0;

    $(".loadMoreProducts").click(function(){
        loaded_products += 4;

        var dati = "welcome/get_products/" + loaded_products;

        $.ajax({
          url:'welcome/get_products/' + loaded_products,
          type: 'post',
          data: {already_used: products},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {

            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

            $("#mainContainerProductWelcome").append(obj.view);
      already_used += obj.ids;

            if(loaded_products >= products - 4) {
                $(".loadMoreProducts").hide();
            } else {
                // load more still visible
            }
          },
          error: function() {
            // there's something wrong
          }
        });

        // show spinner on ajax request starts
        $(".loading-spinner").ajaxStart(function(){
            $(".loading-spinner").show();
            $(".text-load").hide();
        });

        // ajax request complets hide spinner
        $(".loading-spinner").ajaxStop(function(){
            $(".loading-spinner").delay(5000).hide();
            $(".text-load").show();
        });

        return false;
    });

    // submit form contact
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        // click on load more btn
        $(".loadMoreProducts").click();
        return false;
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to keep track of the products you've already queried, throw their id's in an array, and then use something like a where not in.  So something like this:

```
    function getAllProductsLimit($offset=0, $already_used = array(0))
    {
      $this->db->order_by('productID', 'RANDOM');
      $this->db->where_not_in('productID', $already_used);
      $query = $this->db->get('product', 4, $offset);

      if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }

NEW CONTROLLER

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $data['title'] = "Scopri i nostri prodotti";
        $data['description'] = "Description";
        $data['keywords'] = "Keywords";
        $data['products'] = $this->abitainterni->getAllProductsLimit();
        $data['get_products'] = $this->abitainterni->get_products();
        $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
    }

    function get_products($offset)
    {
        $already_used = $this->input->post('already_used');
        $already = explode(',', $already_used);
        $data['products'] = $this->abitainterni->getAllProductsLimit($offset, $already);
        $arr['view'] = $this->load->view('get_products', $data, true);
            $bossy = '';
    foreach($data['products'] as $p)
            {
        $bossy .= $->productID.',';
            }
            $arr['view'] = $bam;
            $arr['ids'] = $bossy;
echo json_encode($arr);
return;

    }

NEW SCRIPT

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        <?
    $like_a_boss = '';
    foreach($get_products as $gp):?>
    $like_a_boss .= $gp->productID.',';
    endforeach;?>

    var products = '<?= $like_a_boss; ?>';
    var loaded_products = 0;

    $(".loadMoreProducts").click(function(){
        loaded_products += 4;

        var dati = "welcome/get_products/" + loaded_products;

        $.ajax({
          url:'welcome/get_products/' + loaded_products,
          type: 'post',
          data: {already_used: products},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

            $("#mainContainerProductWelcome").append(obj.view);
            already_used += obj.ids;           

            if(loaded_products >= products - 4) {
                $(".loadMoreProducts").hide();
            } else {
                // load more still visible
            }
          },
          error: function() {
            // there's something wrong
          }
        });

        // show spinner on ajax request starts
        $(".loading-spinner").ajaxStart(function(){
            $(".loading-spinner").show();
            $(".text-load").hide();
        });

        // ajax request complets hide spinner
        $(".loading-spinner").ajaxStop(function(){
            $(".loading-spinner").delay(5000).hide();
            $(".text-load").show();
        });

        return false;
    });

    // submit form contact
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
        // click on load more btn
        $(".loadMoreProducts").click();
        return false;
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Then whereever your using that function, before you echo out your results to your ajax function, run a quick foreach to add the ids of the products you just got to the already used array.  You can either store this is session, or pass it back and forth between your ajax stuff, or if your ajax stuff is written fine, you don't need to worry about it, just attach the product id's to each product you're displaying using a data attribute or something and generate the array that way.

Comment: Thank you for your help, When I did a foreach to load products into the page, if I don't understand badly, before this:

<?
  if($products!=0){
   foreach($products as $p){
?>

I've to check $already_used var?

Comment: well, if you want to keep the product id's in session, you can do that foreach but it would be before you make your call to the database.  I can show you some code if you post your initial controller that loads the page with the first 4 products as well as the ajax response controller.

Comment: see my edit.  Its untested but if there are any errors they should be pretty easily fixed if you review the code.

Comment: There's something wrong with the script, can you help and check I've fixed everything? See my edit please.

Comment: console:
`SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`

I think the problem is due to the transfer of data via Ajax, because this error appears only when I scroll down the page and the script call the Ajax function. Right?

Comment: check the network tab(in chrome console) and see what the ajax call is acually returning.  Its probably just a syntax error on the server side script.  thats generally what causes that.  the script echoing something thats not a json i mean.  actually comment out the part that says $arr['view'] = $bam;  its instantiating that variable twice and bam isn't actually set so thats probably your server error.

Comment: Ok if i comment out `$arr['view'] = $bam;` the call start, into the console I've got: `Can't find variable: already_used` and `JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'` what's the point? where am I wrong?

Comment: the json parse is being cause by the other error.  So figure out why already used isn't being found and youre all good.

Comment: I've to define `var already_used = "";`? Before I was passing data through `var dati = "welcome/get_products/" + loaded_products;`.
Can you explain me this `data: {already_used: products},`, I didn't get it.

Comment: i just prefer using post array to get or uri segments.  slightly more secure.

Comment: Can you help me? I can't find a solution.

Comment: is this page anywhere I can look at it?  or can you throw it all in a js fiddle?

Comment: I've uploaded all (codeigniter, database) online [here](http://simonerama.com/loadmore.zip) If you can help me I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey John, sorry, have you got some news?

Comment: sorry I'm kind of busy with my own stuff so I don't know when I'll have time to look at your stuff.  You should just debug it step by step until you find the error.